# PostgreSQL - What is the easiest way to convert seconds in a numeric field to MM:SS

Tags: datetime, postgresql

I have field with an integer value which means number of seconds. I would want to display it as MM:SS, **without** hours, so for example 6000 seconds should be shown as 100:00.
What's the easiest way to do this? As far as I see, to_char cannot be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of workaround, as I haven't found better solution:

You could use a simple select:

```
test=# select (6022/60)::TEXT || ':' || (6022%60)::TEXT;
 ?column? 
----------
 100:22
(1 row)
```

This could be wrapped in a nice function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION format(integer) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
  select ($1/60)::TEXT || ':' || ($1%60)::TEXT;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Example of usage:

```
test=# SELECT format(6);
 format 
--------
 0:6
(1 row)

test=# SELECT format(60);
 format 
--------
 1:0
(1 row)

test=# SELECT format(600);
 format 
--------
 10:0
(1 row)

test=# SELECT format(6000);
 format 
--------
 100:0
(1 row)
```